# Finding a video's aspect in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I'm looking for a way to find either a video's aspect ratio in Objective-C (C would be fine as well though).  I'm using a QTMovie if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from the documentation, the QTMovieNaturalSizeAttribute of the movieAttributes dictionary should give an NSValue -valueWithSize: which is the natural size of the movie. So e.g.

```
NSDictionary *movieAttributes = [movie movieAttributes];
NSValue *naturalSizeValue = [movieAttributes objectForKey:QTMovieNaturalSizeAttribute];
CGSize naturalSize = [naturalSizeValue CGSizeValue];
NSLog(@"Aspect ratio is %0.2f", naturalSize.width / naturalSize.height);
```

Should give 1.33 for traditional 4:3 television content, 1.78 for 16:9 widescreen content and possibly other aspect ratios for film content.